# How long will the PostgreSQL user password expire when the valuntil value in pq_user is NULL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Today, a magic happen to our read-only user in our PostgreSQL database. We can't log in to the database using provided username and password. It supposed to be someone changed the password, but no one. When I check the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_user WHERE usename='readonlyuser';
```

I know the fact that valuntil value is totally different between the read-only user and normal user. valuntil value for the normal user is infinity, and NULL for the read-only user. And my question is: How long will the PostgreSQL user password expire when the valuntil value in pq_user is NULL?

Comment: What's the exact error when you try to log in?

Comment: The error says that `password authentication failed`. I already solve the problem by login using another user, but I still curious about `valuntil` default expiry time when we do not set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password will not expire if `valuntil = NULL`.

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.html):

> **rolvaliduntil**     Password expiry time (only used for password authentication); null if no expiration

pg_user is view for pg_shadow with is view for pg_authid

Comment: Could you elaborate on any differences between `rolvaliduntil=infinity` and `rolvaliduntil=null`? It seems both values produce the same behavior.